# The ending of The Daughter

Tags: plot-explanation, the-daughter

Does Hedvig die at the end of the movie? I wasn't sure.

At the end of the movie ***The Daughter***, does Hedvig die or is this a cliff hanger?

Comment: Good question. She's obviously not dead at the end of the movie. Still you could call it a cliff hanger because it is not clear what will happen next.

Answer (score 0):

According to the plot summary on [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Daughter_(2015_film)):

> Oliver and Charlotte reunite in the hospital, where **Hedvig recovers from the unsuccessful suicide attempt.**